# postgres composite index design

Tags: index, performance, postgresql, query-performance

In my rails application using the Postgres database, I have a table called `tw_schedules` which belongs to a `scenarios` table (one `scenario` to many `tw_schedules`). In addition to the `scenario_id` foreign key (primary key "`id`" column from scenarios table), it contains two more foreign keys: type_well_id (primary key "id" column from type_wells table) and tw_import_id (primary key "id" column from tw_imports table).

Each tw_schedules belonging to a particular scenario can either have a type_well_id or tw_import_id, but not both.  This is an application enforced constraint with the result that type_well_id or tw_import_id can have a null value.

My question is: in order to optimize the query retrieval time, should I create two compound indexes on:

```
scenario_id + type_well_id
```

and

```
scenario_id + tw_import_id
```

or three individual indexes on columns:

```
scenario_id
type_well_id
tw_import_id
```

The reason I ask is that both `type_well_id` and `tw_import_id` columns can contain `null` values.

Comment: I would be good if you formatted the code as code (see my edits) or - even better - added the `CREATE TABLE` statements. People will read code easier this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try making two composite partial indexes like

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON tw_schedules (scenario_id, type_well_id) WHERE type_well_id IS NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX idx2 ON tw_schedules (scenario_id, tw_import_id) WHERE tw_import_id IS NOT NULL;
```

But, of course, everything depends on the selectivity of these indexes.